# 1990s-2000s horror alien movie with slugs infecting people through the mouth

Tags: story-identification, horror, alien-invasion

I've seen this horror movie in early to mid-2000s, but the quality wasn't really good, so I suppose the movie could've been older.

The main theme is some kind of alien invasion, where aliens are little slugs which infect people through the mouth.

The one thing I remember really good: the scene where college students are playing American football, one of the players gets knocked off by the infected one and while the infected one stands above knocked down on all fours, the slug falls off from his mouth to the uninfected.

I've done some research and it's not likely one of these movies, as I couldn't find the football scene there:

- [Slither (2006)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slither_(2006_film))
- [Night of the Creeps (1986)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Creeps)
- [Slugs (1988)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slugs_(1988_film))

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jINw-tUXIgg?

Comment: @Valorum looks an awful lot like it. Post an answer?

Comment: oddly enough-only 1 person dies in the entire movie......one of my favorites because of that 71 Chevelle

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [*The Faculty*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133751/) (1998).

The film features a prominent American football scene

And you get to see the brain slugs entering someone and taking them over on multiple occasions (warning: NSFW - gory)